# eigenvalue of orthogonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

i have  following question and my suppose about it and please tell me  if i am wrong or not,if we take some random matrix

```
A=rand(3,3)

A =

    0.8147    0.9134    0.2785
    0.9058    0.6324    0.5469
    0.1270    0.0975    0.9575
```

and make it's SVD
[U E V]=svd(A)

```
U =

   -0.6612   -0.4121   -0.6269
   -0.6742   -0.0400    0.7375
   -0.3290    0.9103   -0.2513


E =

    1.8168         0         0
         0    0.8389         0
         0         0    0.1815


V =

   -0.6557   -0.3056    0.6904
   -0.5848   -0.3730   -0.7204
   -0.4777    0.8761   -0.0658
```

i will get orthogonal matrices,now if i do  SVD on each matrix,for example on U

```
[U1 E1 V1]=svd(U)

U1 =

   -0.0882   -0.6612    0.7450
   -0.3656   -0.6742   -0.6417
    0.9266   -0.3290   -0.1823


E1 =

    1.0000         0         0
         0    1.0000         0
         0         0    1.0000


V1 =

         0    1.0000         0
    0.8944         0   -0.4472
   -0.4472         0   -0.8944
```

i got diagonal matrix with entries  $1$,i as thinking if why it is  so?does it work only for  orthogonal matrces got by SVD decomposition or in general every orthogonal matrix satisfy it?i remembered that basci idea of eigenvalue using geometrical interpretation is

to compress/stretch/change direction of vector

$A*x=\lambda *x$

because orthogonal matrix preserves length(it is isometric transformation)maybe that why every orthogonal matrix has eigenvalues as  $1$,am i right?thanks in advance

Comment: compare: [ http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=SVD+%7B%7B+0.8147%2C++++0.9134%2C++++0.2785%7D%2C%7B+++++0.9058%2C++++0.6324%2C++++0.5469%7D%2C%7B+++++0.1270%2C++++0.0975%2C++++0.9575%7D%7D ]

Comment: i am taking  SVD not on original matrix,but on left side matrix,on U

Comment: there in WA you can continue to experiment

Comment: of course  we are studying from experiment :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The singular values of $A$ (i.e. the diagonal values of $E$ given in the singular value decomposition) are the square roots of the non-zero eigenvalues of $A\cdot A^*$. see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition

The singular values of a unitary matrix are thus the square roots of its eigenvalues. But the eigenvalues of a unitary matrix are all 1.

In other words: you are correct that an orthogonal matrix is an isometry so that all of its eigenvalues are 1 and this is why its singular values are 1.

Comment: so it works on every orthogonal matrices without SVD right?

Comment: @datadatuashvili Yes. For the same reason.

Comment: thanks and wish you everything best in your live